# How to remove duplicate records by taking last record in each group

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to get your opinion about my problem. I am working on a project that stores publications from google scholar. So, when I store the data, it is displayed like that.

```
ID| COLUMN1                          | COLUMN2
1 | 'Knowledge and Data Engineering' | 'IEEE transactions on 16 (1)'
1 | 'Knowledge and Data Engineering' | 'IEEE transactions on 16 (1) 28-40 '
2 | 'Data Engineering'               | '1999. Proceedings.'
2 | 'Data Engineering'               | '1999. Proceedings. 15th International Conference on '
2 | 'Data Engineering'               | '1999. Proceedings. 15th International Conference on 146-153'
3 | 'ACM SIGMOD Record 30 (2)'       | '187-198'
```

I hope you understood my table-like drawing. What I wanted to do is if there are same ID's on consecutive rows, having the last rows.

```
ID| COLUMN1                          | COLUMN2
1 | 'Knowledge and Data Engineering' | 'IEEE transactions on 16 (1) 28-40 '
2 | 'Data Engineering'               | '1999. Proceedings. 15th International Conference on 146-153'
3 | 'ACM SIGMOD Record 30 (2)'       | '187-198'
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Google `ROW_NUMBER()`

Comment: Is there a reason as to why you cannot use `DISTINCT`?

Comment: What do you consider the "last" row? Just the one random row that happens to come last in a query? Or is there some column to indicate an order?

Comment: LOOKS LIKE ID column is duplicating so i guess it is not Identity.if you just want to select unique values then select distinct * from table should give you distinct records

Comment: actually, these values are from a view. I preprocessed the values three times before storing them into the view. I could not have what I want after using distinct.

Comment: To avoid this case please always set the UNIQUE-Flag to your columns so there is always only one row with a specific value.

[UNIQUE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the **[ROW_NUMBER()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186734.aspx)** windows function to produce a sequential number per `ID`, from which you would want to take the last / highest row number.

> **ROW_NUMBER()** : Returns the sequential number of a row within a partition of a result set, starting at 1 for the first row in each partition.

So I broke down the problem into 2 steps:

1. Creating a #temp table with the row numbers included
2. Selecting the rows from that temp table with the highest row number per group

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a8809/1)</kbd>

**MS SQL Server 2012 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Publications
    ([ID] int, [COLUMN1] varchar(34), [COLUMN2] varchar(63))
;

INSERT INTO Publications
    ([ID], [COLUMN1], [COLUMN2])
VALUES
    (1, '''Knowledge and Data Engineering''', '''IEEE transactions on 16 (1)'''),
    (1, '''Knowledge and Data Engineering''', '''IEEE transactions on 16 (1) 28-40 '''),
    (2, '''Data Engineering''', '''1999. Proceedings.'''),
    (2, '''Data Engineering''', '''1999. Proceedings. 15th International Conference on '''),
    (2, '''Data Engineering''', '''1999. Proceedings. 15th International Conference on 146-153'''),
    (3, '''ACM SIGMOD Record 30 (2)''', '''187-198''')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
-- INSERT VALUES INTO TEMP TABLE WITH ROW_NUMBER
SELECT  ID ,
        Column1 ,
        Column2 ,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID ) RowNo
INTO #TEMP
FROM    Publications

-- SELECT ROW FOR EACH ID WITH MAX ROW_NUMBER
SELECT  T1.ID, T1.Column1, T1.Column2
FROM    #TEMP T1
WHERE RowNo = (SELECT MAX(RowNo) FROM #TEMP T2 WHERE T1.ID = T2.ID)
ORDER BY ID
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a8809/1/0)**:

```
| ID | COLUMN1                          | COLUMN2                                                       |
|----|----------------------------------|---------------------------------------------------------------|
|  1 | 'Knowledge and Data Engineering' | 'IEEE transactions on 16 (1) 28-40 '                          |
|  2 | 'Data Engineering'               | '1999. Proceedings. 15th International Conference on 146-153' |
|  3 | 'ACM SIGMOD Record 30 (2)'       | '187-198'                                                     |
```

Comment: @Elesmoth it's hardly beautiful, but glad it helped you :)

Comment: By the way, I have 950-1000 rows in my result table, there are 5 problematic rows like that. Because of that, I want to solve it in an additional approximation.

Comment: In addition, is there a way to store temp table's data into a view. Because, program will call a view or table.

Comment: You could either rewrite the query so that it uses a subquery instead of a temp table or you could use the results of the temp table to delete any rows in the source table that it flags as duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH CTE AS( 
SELECT Id,
       Column1,
       Column2, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Column1 ORDER BY Id DESC) AS rownum
       )
SELECT Id, Column1, column2
FROM CTE 
WHERE rownum = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM
    (
        SELECT ID, COLUMN1, COLUMN2, ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
        (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID DESC) AS ROWID FROM YOUR_TABLE
    ) AS A
WHERE ROWID = 1
```

Comment: I could not run the code that you wrote. 'Where' could not be recognized.

Comment: just put 'AS A' before where. I forgot to put alias. try now

Comment: It returns first value which I do not want to get. But thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

This Question has asked a million times

WITH cteDup AS (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY COLUMN1) 'Rank'
             FROM Table)

to permanently remove use this

```
DELETE FROM cteDup
    WHERE Rank > 1
```

otherwise

```
select top 20 * from cteDup where Rownumber = 1
```